# Why/When may StorageFolder.CreateFolderAsync fail?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, storagefolder

The documentation for [`StorageFolder.CreateFolderAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227257.aspx) says: "If you try to create a subfolder in a virtual folder like a library or a file group, this method may fail". That's all, no further details.

Does anyone have some deeper knowledge or experience regarding this issue? Why/When/Under what circumstances may creation fail? And what does "fail" mean? An exception is thrown (which one)? Silent failure?

Comment: Limited storage space seems like an obvious candidate.

Comment: I am here for the answer of this question only. :(